# Wix Burn Loose File Install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, burn

Copying of license files using Wix 3.10.2? We have a requirement where we need copy some license files after the installation of the webapplication to IIS. Copying of license files will be the last in the sequence. The license files will reside next to the burn (bootstrapper) setup.exe. This way we can control what license file need to be installed based on the user. I am trying to understand if there will be an issue with number of license files reside along with .exe? Is there a custom action to pick files that are not part of the msi or exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to be more precise about exactly when you want the copy to occur. Your original question says "after the installation" which implies that the install has finished and that your generated MSI is no longer running. but in a later comment you say "during the install".

If after the install is what you want, then you could add a custom executable to your Burn bundle that will do whatever you want. In many of these kinds of situations the application that needs the file just goes and gets it with help from the MSI saying where it was installed from, or by using the SourceList capabilities of Windows Installer to get the location.

If you want to copy files during the install then the CopyFile element is probably what you need. It has wildcard capability to define the files you want to copy. Your source location will be the SourceDir property and the destination will be one of your defined directories. Note that the files will not be uninstalled when the product is uninstalled.

WiX Copyfile:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html

Comment: I have updated my initial question to clarify. The license files is part of the installation. But it is done at the end of the sequence. I would like to confirm with you that if we need to have all *.lic files as part of the msi compilation for CopyFile element to work?

Comment: Yes it works, that's what it's for. As a test I just copied two .txt files using *.txt from next to the MSI into the main install folder.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this with CopyFile:                 `<Component Id="LicenseFile" Guid="">
    <CopyFile Id="Copy" Delete="no" DestinationDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" SourceName="*.lic" SourceProperty="CURRENTDIRECTORY" />    
 </Component>`

Comment: So loose file support with wildcard search is not possible with burn.?

Comment: Yes it's possible, just read the docs and start testing. As I said, I copied *.txt therefore you can copy *.lic

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW it works fine with in MSI. When the msi is bundled using burn. The CopyFile element is not working. Is this because of cache functionality in burn? The *.lic files are not part of burn compilation.

Answer (score 1):

1) There will not be an issue with number of license files residing along with exe

2) Using the Media element without a Cabinet name you can specify that certain files will neither be inside a cab or embedded into the msi, no custom action needed. See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/media.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But do I have to compile the license files as part of the burn project every time? Can I use some kind of a script which resides inside the exe that will look for any license files in the same directory as exe to copy them to install directory. That way user can just copy the required license files before install and execute the exe.

Comment: Windows Installer is designed to know which files are being installed so that it can properly repair, rollback, and uninstall them when necessary. An installer that will copy any generic file breaks the design and benefits of using Windows Installer in the first place. You may be better off using a different technology. Writing a custom action that can correctly install, rollback, uninstall, and repair generic files is going to be difficult.

Comment: Yeah it is hard to believe tool like Wix not able to perform simple copy files based on the extension during install from source directory.

Comment: Windows Installer can do anything using custom actions, but you will find it hard to do it right. The wix toolset makes it easy to do the right thing, but hard to do the wrong thing. Most people see that as a good thing. Keep reading and learning about Windows Installer and custom actions, there's lots of info out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use native bootstrap that comes with Visual Studio SDK. With the bootstrap you can also create pre-requisite like installing .net. This worked for my requirement. Also there is a msbuild task so that you can automate it. Used setup project to create msi and VS bootstrap to create setup.exe